# Problems with xampp

Tags: php, sql-server, php-mssql

I can not recognize the SQL Server command in XAMPP 1.8.1 and PHP 5.4.7, this code had already used it and it worked before but now it doesn't.

I have already tried to put the `php_mssql.dll` dll and still don't recognize the command:

```php
$con = mssql_connect('187.164.1.2/base','pag','123') or die('Could not connect to the server!');
mssql_select_db('aguacom') or die('Could not select a database.');
```

I expected it to connect to the other server's database.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: call undefined function mssql_connect

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to MS SQL Server using [MSSQL PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php) (`mssql_` functions), but this extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7.0.0.

What you can do is to install [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (`sqlsrv_` functions). You need to download:

- The appropriate version of this driver - for PHP 5.4 you need version 3.2 (32-bit or 64-bit depending on the PHP version)
- The appropriate ODBC driver.

Note, that MSSQL PHP extension (`php_mssql.dll`) and PHP Driver for SQL Server (`php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`) are two different PHP extensions.

Example using `mssql_` functions:

```
<?php
$server = "187.164.1.2/base";
$username = "pag";
$password = "123";
$database = "aguacom";

$conn = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Unable to connect. ".mssql_get_last_message()."</br>";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected.</br>";
}
mssql_select_db($database, $conn);

// ...

mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Example using `sqlsrv_` functions:

```
<?php
$server = "187.164.1.2/base";
$username = "pag";
$password = "123";
$database = "aguacom";

$connectionInfo = array(
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password,
    "Database" => $database
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Unable to connect. ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)."</br>";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected.</br>";
}

// ...

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should enable mssql in xampp**

things you need  [download these files]: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

**Add downloaded files in php.ini like this way**

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

**restart apache and then check**

```
<?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); ?>
```

credits goes to **rray**

Comment: but do I need version 56 or 54 ?, because I have php 5.4.7

Comment: it does support  
    Version 4.0 supports PHP 7.0+ on Windows and Linux
    Version 3.2 supports PHP 5.6, 5.5, and 5.4 on Windows
    Version 3.1 supports PHP 5.5 and 5.4 on Windows
    Version 3.0 supports PHP 5.4 on Windows

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 you just read in system requirements,you can use 7 or 5.x too

Comment: Your answer is using mssql, sqlsrv and pdo as interchangeable terms. They're actually three different extensions (although sqlsrv also includes a pdo driver).